# Function just stopped working and started showing error - Python Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created this function to extract data and resample it from MySQL database and it was working perfectly until today and it just stopped working whereas when I run individual lines of code it works perfectly but not in a function, what am I missing here, please bear with me I am a newbie

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import mysql.connector as sql

def get_hist(df):
    db = sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',database='algo')
    df = pd.read_sql('select *from ticks',con=db)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='s',utc=True)
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
    df = df.set_index(['date'])
    ticks = df.loc[:,['last_price']]
    df = ticks['last_price'].resample('5min').ohlc().dropna()  
    return df


Error:get_hist(df)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-2bb88ed963bc>", line 1, in <module>
    get_hist(df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: We cannot copy paste and run your code. Please consider writing a full working minimal example,see: MRE here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so we can have a look. Show us how you are calling your function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need the `df` argument in the function definition (`def get_hist(df):`) so try `def get_hist():` instead.

Comment: Thankyou bro , it worked , such a silly mistake from my side lol